# C's null character, with reference to Ex.9 of "Learn C the Hard Way"

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am working on Ex. 9 of Learn C the Hard Way: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex9.html

I have several questions:

1. Why must the null character be manually entered when the char name is specified character-by-character (under the "// setup the name" comment), but not when using the method, char *another = "Zed"? Why don't we have to type char *another = "Zed\0" ?
2. With regard to the code under the comment "// first, print them out raw" -- he says that both the integer array and number array are filled with 0s after the first character (since only one character is specified for each array). So, why is it that when he prints these arrays, the integer array displays 0 0 0 0 but the character array displays only a solitary a, instead of a 0 0 0?
3. When he sets up the number array, why doesn't he need to include the null character, like in the name array?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The string literal `"a"` denotes an array of characters `{ 'a', '\0' }`.

Comment: If you have three questions, could you ask three questions?  Also reframe them in a way that doesn't depend on a work under copyright.  On StackOverflow it is preferred if the source being commented on appears in the question, but simply copying and pasting this source here for a commercial work may not be permitted.  Try putting it "in your own words" and asking one question-per-question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not contain the pertinent code inline.

Comment: Sorry, I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. An array of characters may not be a string (with a trailing \0), but a sequence of characters enclosed in double-quotes is (and thus the compiler knows to add the \0 at the end).
2. Because \0, which indicates the end of the string, has the ascii value 0.
3. Because it is not a string, it is an array of `int`s.

Comment: Thanks, let me check if I really understand (2). You're saying that the int array, when printed, results in 0 0 0 0 because the zeroes are treated as integers (as opposed to a string, and thus not terminated by 0), but the char array, when printed, is interpreted as a string and therefore the first 0 terminates it, resulting in just "a"?

Comment: @intelli78: That is why `name` appears as just an `a`.  As St0fF says, the reason `name each` only shows an `a` is because NUL (the character with ascii value 0) is non-printable.

Answer (score 4):

1. Because when declaring a string as a string, the compiler will add the terminating NUL to the array automagically.  The other variant is "declaring an array of chars" -> see point (3), where you'd have to give the terminator manually if you wanted to use it as a string.
2. Either because the character NUL is non-printable, or because you printed it as a string (which is terminated by the first NUL, stopping to display further characters.
3. because number-arrays (`int arrayname[count of elements]`) does not need a terminator - the programmer has to take measures to not access the array out-of-bounds.

Comment: There is no character `NULL`, that's a nullpointer-constant. Do you perchance mean `NUL`?

Comment: Sry, yes I did - updated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Strings in C are \0 terminated by default. Anything you produce with "" will end with a \0. Array initializers are not \0 terminated by default.

"Hi" is the same as {'H', 'i', '\0'}.

2. When the computer prints a string in your terminal it needs to know when the string ends. This can be achieved either by telling the computer how long the string is, or by telling it to stop when it reaches a certain character. The \0 character is actually just a normal 0 you can put in a string, and 0 happens to be the string stop indicator in C.
3. When accessing the number array, you already know how long it is, and you ask for it to print elements you know exist. If you would have asked the computer to deal with an array of elements, rather than specific elements, the computer would either need to recognize some stop number, or know how long the array is.

Comment: What is an *array literal*?

Comment: A literal is a value you write into your program code. An array literal is an array written in your code, such as `int xs[] = {1,2,3}`; The literal part is the {1,2,3} part.

Comment: Sry, but that's so wrong. You might like to read a bit of the standard to (un-)confuse your terminology.

Comment: C does not have *array literals*. `{1, 2, 3}` is an initializer composed of an initializer list of integer constants.

Comment: @Emanuel: That is rather called "array initializer". Array literal might be confused with compound literals (e.g. anynoumous arrays from C99/C11).

Comment: True. `1`, `'a'`, and `"hello"` are integer, character, and string literals (or constants), but `{1,2,3}` is an array (or list) initializer. I assumed there would be array literals because there are string literals, but I guess I was wrong.